# Xamarin Forms: How to make dynamically created items clickable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

In my application I am adding menu items dynamically.

Is it possible to make items clickable so that it can take me to, for example, "Page2" or "Page3"?

Here is my code in **AppShell.xaml.cs**

```
public ObservableCollection<dynamic> FlyoutItems { get; set; }

public AppShell()
{
            FlyoutItems = new ObservableCollection<dynamic>()
            {
                new {  MenuTitle="MenuTitle1" },
                new {  MenuTitle="MenuTitle2" },
                new {  MenuTitle="MenuTitle3" },
                new {  MenuTitle="MenuTitle4" }
            };
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;
}
```

**AppShell.xaml**

```
<Shell.FlyoutContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <ListView x:Name="MenuItemsListView"
                          SeparatorVisibility="None"
                          HasUnevenRows="true"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding FlyoutItems}">
                    <ListView.Header>
                        <Grid BackgroundColor="CornflowerBlue">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
                                   TextColor="#d7d9b4"
                                   Text="{Binding Title}"
                                   FontSize="24"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ListView.Header>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Padding="15,10"
                                             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                    <Label VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                           Text="{Binding Type}"
                                           TextColor="Black"
                                           FontSize="20"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.FlyoutContentTemplate>
```

I think I need to create a button but  I am not quite sure how to do it.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks!

Comment: ListView has both ItemTapped and ItemSelected events

Comment: Thanks @Jason, I dont know how to "upvote" this but it helped!